# Excel Table: matching a user name to a user key

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In my Excel file, I have a list of user names and each one of them has their unique user key. 
On one sheet, I have all the user names and keys in two columns as follows:

```
Column B      Column C
User Key1     User Name1
User Key2     User Name2
```

On another sheet, I have certain information that has been performed by an user. But instead of having the user name, I have the user key.

I would like to have the user name under the action and not the user key. 
Is there a formula or a trick so that I can perform this?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.
[image: spreadsheets, as described above]

Comment: **VLOOKUP** function can help you: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1

Answer (score 0):

In the first sheet you have to sort by key (by column B) and then in the other sheet you can apply a Vlookup formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP (value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])
```

value = a reference to the key for example: `=C2`

table = the sheet of keys `'Sheet1'(B1:C100)`

col_index= The column where is the data you want, in this case is `2`
range_lookup = Put it to `FALSE`

More information about `vlookup` [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function)